# C2DM, IOException when sending message

Tags: java, android

I can't get the sending part of C2DM to work. I get IOException at OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();

```
public void sendMessage() throws IOException{       
                String key = readFileAsString("acct/"+to+"/key");

                StringBuilder postDataBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                postDataBuilder.append("registration_id").append("=").append(key);
                postDataBuilder.append("&").append("collapse_key").append("=").append("0");
                postDataBuilder.append("&").append("data.payload").append("=").append(URLEncoder.encode(to+"--"+"acct/"+to+"/1", UTF8));
                byte[] postData = postDataBuilder.toString().getBytes(UTF8);

                URL url = new URL("https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send");

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postData.length));                   
                conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth=" + cl);

             //------------------
                OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
             //--------------------------
                out.write(postData);
                out.close();

                int sw =conn.getResponseCode();
                System.out.println(""+sw);
                switch (sw) {
                    case 200:
                        System.out.println("Success, but check for errors in the body");
                        break;
                    case 503:
                        System.out.println("Service unavailable");
                        break;
                    case 401:
                        System.out.println(" Invalid authentication token");
                        break;
                 }

            }
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is message that come with IOException? Or it hasn't message?

Comment: It would help if you posted the actual error message and stack trace as that will help to locate the problem.

Comment: It only shows "Problem with Communication Server" from catch (IOException e) 
         { 
          System.err.println("Problem with Communication Server");
          System.exit(1); 
         }    . The SendMessage object is within a try-catch inside another class.

Comment: For a test, rather than having the catch block eat the error and print out a standard message, change it to print out the exception and its associated stacktrace, i.e., `e.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: Here :javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching android.apis.google.com found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution most commonly given to resolve the error message you are receiving is to define a custom Hostname validation.  The main problem that you are facing is that the domain name returned by Google's Android URL is *.google.com.  Unfortunately, this causes some issues as the Android SDK is at android.apis.google.com.  The JVM will not validate this combination by default (*.sdk.google.com would be acceptable).

Here is an example of how you can create your own hostname validator:

```
    URL url = new URL("https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send");

    HostnameVerifier hVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession
                session) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setHostnameVerifier(hVerifier);
```

If you change your code to something similar to above, the error you mentioned should be corrected.

**EDIT**
Here is some test code that is fully functional in my dev environment.  Just updated the authentication information with your application specific information to run:

```
public class C2DMTest {


    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        String auth = authorize();
        if (auth == null) {
            System.out.println("No authorization returned");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        sendMessage(auth);
    }

    /**
     * Perform an authorization request to access Google's C2DM
     * API.
     *
     * @return The retrieved authorization request.
     */
    private static String authorize() throws Exception {
        String accountType = "GOOGLE";
        String service = "ac2dm";

        String source = "replace-me";
        String email = "replace-me";
        String passwd = "replace-me";


        StringBuilder params = new StringBuilder();
        params.append("accountType=").append(accountType)
                .append("&Email=").append(URLEncoder.encode(email, UTF8))
                .append("&Passwd=").append(URLEncoder.encode(passwd, UTF8))
                .append("&service=").append(service)
                .append("&source=").append(source);
        byte[] postData = params.toString().getBytes(UTF8);

        URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postData.length));

        //------------------
        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
        //--------------------------
        out.write(postData);
        out.close();

        int sw = conn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("" + sw);

        switch (sw) {
            case 503:
                System.out.println("Service unavailable");
                break;
            case 401:
                System.out.println(" Invalid authentication token");
                break;
            default:
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
                int len = -1;
                while ((len = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    baos.write(bytes, 0, len);
                }
                in.close();
                String input = baos.toString();
                Map<String, String> res = parseResponse(input);
                return res.get("Auth");
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Parses a response string into a usable data map.
     *
     * @param response The response from Google
     * @return A Map representation.
     */
    private static Map<String, String> parseResponse(String response) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        if (response != null) {
            String[] lines = response.split("\n");
            for (String line : lines) {
                String[] parts = line.split("=");
                if (parts.length == 2) {
                    map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
                }
            }
        }
        return map;
    }

    private static String UTF8 = "UTF-8";


    /**
     * Send message to mobile device.
     *
     * @param cl Google API auth code.
     */
    public static void sendMessage(String cl) throws IOException {
        String key = "invalid";

        StringBuilder postDataBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        postDataBuilder.append("registration_id").append("=").append(key);
        postDataBuilder.append("&").append("collapse_key").append("=").append("0");
        postDataBuilder.append("&").append("data.payload").append("=").append(URLEncoder.encode("test-content", UTF8));
        byte[] postData = postDataBuilder.toString().getBytes(UTF8);

        URL url = new URL("https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send");

        HostnameVerifier hVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession
                    session) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setHostnameVerifier(hVerifier);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postData.length));
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth="+cl);

        //------------------
        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
        //--------------------------
        out.write(postData);
        out.close();

        int sw = conn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("" + sw);
        switch (sw) {
            case 200:
                System.out.println("Success, but check for errors in the body");
                break;
            case 503:
                System.out.println("Service unavailable");
                break;
            case 401:
                System.out.println(" Invalid authentication token");
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't find the method setHostnameVerifier for HttpsURLConnection. Must something close.

Comment: Are you looking at `HttpURLConnection` or `HttpsURLConnection`?  I have verified that `setHostnameVerifier` exists from Java 1.4 and up.

Comment: at HttpURLConnection. HttpsURLConnection seems deprecated

Comment: Where are you seeing it as deprecated? Where are you running this code: In a mobile application, backend server?  Similar classes from IBM (`com.ibm.net.ssl`), cactus (`org.apache.cactus.util`) and others are deprecated, but the JRE class `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection` should not be as far as I am aware.

Comment: It shows it ok from javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection. But still the same exception :java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching android.apis.google.com found.. Thank you! :)

Comment: I'm not sure why it would still be failing.  I have updated the answer with some functioning test code.  See if that runs for you.  If not, it may be an issue with the JRE or environment in which you are running.

Comment: I finally got it! Thanks :) great job!

Comment: Of course, by not actually verifying the server's certificate this code is vulnerable to a man-in-the-middle attack.